# Hibernate Single Table inheritance with self join

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following classes:

Guide class:

```
public abstract class Guide
{
    private Long idGuide;
    private String name;

    private GuideContainer parent;
    /** GETTERS & SETTERS*/
}
```

GuideContainer:

```
public class GuideContainer extends Guide
{    
   private Guide children;
/** GETTER & SETTERS */
}
```

GuideFile:

```
public class GuideFile extends Guide
{
   private String uri;
/**GETTERS & SETTERS */
}
```

with the following mappings:
For Guide:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Guide" table="guides" abstract="true">
        <id name="idGuide" type="integer" column="idGuide">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="java.lang.String" column="name" />
        <discriminator column="type" type="java.lang.String" />

        <many-to-one class="GuideContainer" fetch="join" name="parent">
            <column name="parent" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

GuideFile:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass extends="Guide" name="GuideFile" discriminator-value="file">
        <property name="uri" type="java.lang.String" column="uri" />
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

GuideContainer:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <subclass extends="Guide" name="GuideContainer" discriminator-value="container">
        <set fetch="select" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="children" sort="unsorted" table="children">
            <key>
                <column name="parent" not-null="false" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="Guide" />
        </set>
    </subclass>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to get all the guides with a given parent

```
 Query query = getSession().createQuery("from Guide g where parent = :parent order by type").setParameter("parent", parent);
        List<Guide> guides= query.list();
        return guides;
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
 IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of Guide.idGuide
```

And after that:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Query should have been:

```
from Guide g where parent.idGuide = :parent order by type
```